Virtual paths broken?
So, I have been having a recurring problem with Windows, thought it was a Windows 10 issue, upgraded to 11, suddenly realized it still existed,
Shows unity calling a package with the "g" letter added to its path
It could be seen here that, the unity editor is calling to a package with nearly the correct path, but the added g in front breaks it, same here.
VS code calling node.exe but with g in path
VS code is trying to call node.exe, but a g is added in front. If it works, it looks for its dependencies, which have a "g" in their path. Since there is no folder with "g," it stops working.
Simply analogy with games:
The game path is: D:\Games\Game1
Game data paths are: D:\Games\Game1\Data
I open its .exe
it says there should be a "data" Folder beside the executable file
I raised a Ticket at Microsoft support, and they gave me a few options to do.
I did most of them (environment variables, re-installs, repairs, checks, etc.), but I don't have any idea what one of them is or how to even diagnose it.
Namely virtual paths in the registry

Not a coding question. Try over on superuser.com
